# Getting value type from event found via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I'm trying to get values that were sent as payload with an event that is triggered outside the scope of my assembly. I'm finding an event via reflection.

```
var eventInfo = adCallbackType.GetEvent(eventInfoName);
```

Then subscribe my method to this event.

```
var eventDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, adToBindTo, methodInfo);
eventData.EventInfo.AddEventHandler(adCallbackType, eventData.Delegate);
```

This is the method I'm subscribing to that event

```
public void OnAdReceivedReward(string adUnitId, object reward, object adInfo)
{
   Debug.Log($"id: {adUnitId}");
   Debug.Log($"reward: {reward}"); //this comes corrupted, prints only the Label value
   Debug.Log($"info: {adInfo}");
}
```

I'm not providing the complete code here.

The problem is that one of the events has these type parameters

```
public static event Action<string, AdSdkBase.Reward, AdSdkBase.AdInfo> OnAdReceivedRewardEvent
```

where Reward is a struct, for example

```
public struct Reward
{
   public string Label;
   public int Amount;

   public override string ToString()
   {
      return $"Reward: {Label}, {Amount}";
   }
}
```

So, when `Reward` is passed as a struct, then it comes corrupted in the callback. If I'd change `Reward` to be a class instead, then it works as I expected, but I can't change it, since it comes from 3rd party SDK.
I did not do much with this type of stuff before. Does it has something to do with data marshaling or am I missing something when I'm searching for method and event via reflection? (like binding attributes)

Comment: **Not sure I understand** completely, "corrupted"? I suspect you should box your `Reward` struct into an `object` box yourself at an early state. Because otherwise the struct will be _copied_ when it is boxed implicitly. So instead of using a struct variable like `Reward someReward = new Reward /* ... */;` directly and passing it as object (which will copy the struct, and not let you have an access to that copy), try boxing yourself with `object someRewardBoxed = someReward;` and then pass in `someRewardBoxed` instead. In that way, mutations of the struct can be seen in `someRewardBoxed`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, by "corrupted" I meant that I only see the value of a first public property of the struct in my callback. In my example, I was expected to see `Reward: 5 coins` - which is what ToString() override would do. But instead, when I log the `Reward` in the callback, I just see "coins" which is the value of a property `Label` of that `Reward` struct. The thing is that event is triggered on 3rd party SDK, so I don't have access to modify their code. Working in Unity. attempt to set a breakpoint and see other properties cause Unity to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the signature of the OnAdReceivedReward?

```
public void OnAdReceivedReward(string adUnitId, AdSdkBase.Reward reward, AdSdkBase.AdInfo adInfo){}
```

Or try casting the object reward to it's structure.

```
public void OnAdReceivedReward(string adUnitId, object reward, object adInfo)
{
   AdSdkBase.Reward rew = (AdSdkBase.Reward)reward;
   Debug.Log($"id: {adUnitId}");
   Debug.Log($"reward: {rew}"); //this comes corrupted, prints only the Label value
   Debug.Log($"info: {adInfo}");
}
```

Comment: I can't do it. I just don't have this type here, this is why I use System.object. If it'd be passed properly then I'd be able to do something like `reward.GetType().GetProperties()` to iterate thru the reward's props and re-construct the structure () inside my assembly. But `reward.GetType()` returns `System.String`, but not the `Reward` type...